# Proving that the vector divided by it's magnitude is -1/2

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let $$ \vec v = (x, y, z)$$ and $$~w = (z, x, y)$$ where$$ x + y + z = 0$$ Show that
$$\vec v. \vec w/\Vert v \Vert \Vert w\Vert  = − 1/2$$

Comment: How far have you gotten in your own work on the problem?  Where, in that process did you get stuck?  Actually, it would be most helpful, especially since it's clear you already know mathjax/latex, if you would add your working into your question, itself.

Comment: Ok SO far I did the $$ \vec v * \vec w $$ which I have as $$y^2- xz   z^2-xy x^2-yz)$$

Comment: I'm confused by your Comment above.  When all else fails, it's a good idea to try a simple example.  This can frequently help detect when something is missing in a problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\|v\| = \|w\|$. We have:

$$0=(x+y+z)^2 = \|v\|^2 + 2(xy + xz + yz) = \|v\|^2 + 2 v \cdot w$$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

observe that

$$\|\vec{v}+\vec {w}\|=\|\vec {v}\|=\|\vec {w}\|$$

and square.

Comment: I got  x+z  y+x  z+y when I did v+w.

Comment: @user7112108 but x+y=-z, x+z=-y,...